# Batch Training for large datasets and model with many inputs

Tags: python, keras

I have a keras model with 50 inputs(x1 to x50) and 1 output. I am facing the common problem of training on multiple large files in Keras which are combinely too large to fit on GPU memory.

Initially, I was trying:

```
x1 = np.load('x1_train.npy')
x2 = np.load('x2_train.npy')
x3 = np.load('x3_train.npy')
x4 = np.load('x4_train.npy')
x5 = np.load('x5_train.npy')
x6 = np.load('x6_train.npy')

y_train = pd.read_csv("train_labels.csv")
```

And then fitting the data using:

```
model.fit([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6], y_train, validation_data = ([x1_val,x2_val,x3_val,x4_val,x5_val,x6_val],y_validate), epochs = 15, batch_size = 20, verbose = 2)
```

But the available RAM wasn't sufficient to accommodate the data and hence crash.

Now I am doing:

```
def generate_batches(batch_size):
  while True:
    x1 = np.load('x1_train.npy')
    x2 = np.load('x2_train.npy')
    x3 = np.load('x3_train.npy')
    x4 = np.load('x4_train.npy')
    x5 = np.load('x5_train.npy')
    x6 = np.load('x6_train.npy')

    y_train = pd.read_csv("train_labels.csv")

    for cbatch in range(0, x1.shape[0], batch_size):
      i = cbatch + batch_size
         yield ([x1[cbatch:i,:,:],x2[cbatch:i,:,:],x3[cbatch:i,:,:],x4[cbatch:i,:,:],x5[cbatch:i,:,:],x6[cbatch:i,:,:]], y_train[cbatch:i])
```

I plan to use `fit_generator` for the fitting of the model, but  the above code still crashes.

`x1`,`x2`...`x50` all are of the shape `(77156, 30, 50, 1)`